# ViewPager not working on some devices Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager and Tabpageradapter for swiping one activity to another but I am getting class not found exception below android 4.0 version.

**MainActivity****:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization Viewpager in main activity
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    context = this.getApplicationContext();
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackbox));
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.blackbox));

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

TabsPagerAdapter.class :

```
//Class using for tabs 
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity that is the first activity to open
        return new PunjabiFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity(Second activity to open
        return new HindiFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity(third activity to open
        return new EnglishFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

Getting this error in logcat :

```
Failed resolving Lcom/Neha/awesomestatus/MainActivity; interface 16 'Landroid/app/ActionBar$TabListener;'
W/dalvikvm(837): Link of class 'Lcom/Neha/awesomestatus/MainActivity;' failed
D/AndroidRuntime(837): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(837): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Neha.awesomestatus/com.Neha.awesomestatus.MainActivity}:        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Neha.awesomestatus.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.Neha.awesomestatus-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Neha.awesomestatus.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.Neha.awesomestatus-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

Comment: This kind of error can caused by different  name between your manifest file and activity class name. Make sure the MainActivity class name is  com.Neha.awesomestatus.MainActivity

Comment: On some Devices its working fine like above andorid 4.0 and 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />` instead of `<ViewPager />`   in your xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/compatibility/AndroidSupportV2/src/android/support/v2/view/ViewPager.java?r=3488). Min version for ViewPager is 4.0. For compatibility you can use the library in the link. The second link gives you the compatibility library.

Comment: i am already using this library  android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

Comment: Updated with a second link. I might have forgotten that initially.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Sohaib's answer, pointing that you should use the compatibility library, if you are loading content from a web service, you may need to extend from `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I had some similar problem before and just changing the base PagerAdapter fixed the issue.

Comment: I am not using any content from web . i am using local database and also i am using v4 library

Comment: It's still something that you are not doing in the UI thread, so you can anyway try to substitute FragmentPagerAdapter by FragmentStatePagerAdapter and see if that works for you.

Comment: i am getting depprecated on The method setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) from the type ViewPager is deprecated

Comment: i have used this FragmentStatePagerAdapter but there is no any changed

Answer (score 0):

Carefully look at your `onCreate` method.

In my case I was checking for some permissions and using `return;` if the permission is not granted.

That is why I could not run my app on the marshmallow, but could run my app on the lower versions.